# Why does EF try to insert instance twice with either single or multiple SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following class structure

```
class A { long Id { get; set; } ICollection<B> ManyB { get; set; } }
class B { long Id { get; set; } C { get; set; } }
class C { long Id { get; set; } Name { get; set; } }
```

With an instance graph that looks like this

[image: object graph]

When I add an instance of **A** that has in **ManyB** two different instances of **B** that reference the same instance of **C**, EF attempts to insert **C** twice when I call this code:

```
var a = CreateItAsDescribedAbove();
context.Add(a)
context.SaveChanges();
```

All of the objects above are new; that is they are not existing entities already in the database. When I change the code to the following, I still have the same behavior:

```
var a = CreateItAsDescribedAbove();
A.ManyB
   .Select(b => b.C)
   .DistinctBy(c => c.Id)
   .ForEach(c => context.Add(c));
context.SaveChanges();
context.Add(a)
A.ManyB
   .Select(b => b.C)
   .ForEach(c => context.Entry(c).State = EntityState.Unchanged);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I would've thought forcing EF to treat the objects as unchanged after a prior add should work, but they seemed to be ignored.

How do I convince EF to save my instance of **C** once? Note, I can't simply null out one of the **B.C** because then one of the relationships won't get inserted. I'm not concerned about doing this in a single commit. Just whatever works.

Comment: How does EF know about the relations? Does your database use foreign keys, or do you use fluent mapping? Can you show either?

Comment: How are you creating a? Have you checked that the two Cs are definitely the same object by using Object.ReferenceEquals(C,c)?

Comment: @CodeCaster, I used the fluent mappings, which I know to be correct, and the schema uses foreign keys in expected ways. The case with different `C` instances works fine. I didn't show the maps for this reason.

Comment: @mark_h, `ReferenceEquals` indeed shows them to be the same, which is one reason I'm baffled. The objects were created with simple constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue when using object and Equals operator: when on object is used in a hash tables or dictionary keys, is very importat to override GetHashCode method.

EF uses dictionary for internal context.

Try to override GetHashCode for your classes and you must be sure to return same result for same instance object.

**EDIT:**

EF use internal ObjectStateManager with several dictionary: AddedEntityStore, ModifiedEntityStore, DeletedEntityStore, UnchangedEntityStore (Dictionary<'EntityKey, EntityEntry>).
When EF searchs entities in these dictionary on "SaveChanges", uses TryGetValue method of dictionary.
So, for brevity, this is the code:

```
private int FindEntry(TKey key)
{
    if ((object) key == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    if (this.buckets != null)
    {
    int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & int.MaxValue;
    for (int index = this.buckets[num % this.buckets.Length]; index >= 0; index = this.entries[index].next)
    {
        if (this.entries[index].hashCode == num && this.comparer.Equals(this.entries[index].key, key))
        return index;
    }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

all of us can see this statement:
**this.comparer.GetHashCode(key)**

And this is relevant like use of GetHashCode with Dictionary and HashTable.
See Dino Esposito post: http://software2cents.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/hash-codes-and-equality-in-the-net-framework/

Comment: I've had problems with EF in the past with objects where `Equals` and `GetHashCode` were implemented incorrectly, but in this case, none of the objects have overridden them at all, and that is ok with EF.

Comment: @Kit: ... and that is ok with EF? Sure?

Comment: Absolutely positive.

Comment: There are very obscure cases with EF < 6 where entity classes without a custom `GetHashCode()` _could_ present _some problem_, but it wasn't quite common. Anyway since EF 6 the `GetHashCode()` of the entity classes is ignored.

Comment: This on "private int FindEntry(TKey key)" for EF6: int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & int.MaxValue; So, EF6 use GetHashCode. FindEntity is used to find an instance in added, deleted, modified, unattached entity stores in context

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after a very thorough debugging and another set of eyes, the answer is quite simple: they were *not* the same reference. When I originally posted this I was looking at the wrong property!

Comment: see EDIT in my answer

Comment: Maybe you could give credit to the other set of eyes by accepting their answer :)